# Paho Java - file persistence

Tags: java, mqtt, paho

I have recently started with paho mqtt for java and with mqtt at all and I am stuck with persistence mechanism provided by mqtt broker and paho client it self. Maybe I misunderstood (it's probably that) the concept of persistence in context of mqtt.

**Use case which we have to support is following**: it should be possible that our mqtt client has been disconnected for 7 days (which I highly doubt will ever happen, but OK) and even application to shut down without getting connection back during those 7 days, and once it is up and running to send all the messages for all 7 days while it was disconnected.

Paho client supports persistence of buffered messages while it or a broker were down, and once network is back or broker is up, buffered messages are sent, but it is not possible to send buffered messages if application shuts down while client was disconnected or a broker was unavailable.

Basically my question is - is it possible that disconnected-buffered messages will survive paho client shut down and start again?

Answer (score 0):

The specification states nothing about it, is only especifies:

> A retained message is a normal MQTT message with the retained flag set
>   to true. The broker will store the last retained message and the
>   corresponding QoS for that topic Each client that subscribes to a
>   topic pattern, which matches the topic of the retained message, will
>   receive the message immediately after subscribing. For each topic **only**
>   **one** retained message will be stored by the broker.

As you can see, your clients will only get the last published message for that topic...

everything else behind that is back for good!

Comment: Retained messages are different from queued messages and the persistence in the client

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the `MqttDefaultFilePersistence` and not the `MemoryPersistence` module then the client should queue messages when it can't reach the broker and these queued messages should also survive the client restarting.

The offline buffering is a relatively new feature, but it should be in all the current builds

Comment: Yes, I am using `MqttDefaultFilePersistence`. Case when I stop broker and start it again, works fine - queued messages are sent towards broker once it is up again. But case when **((client is offline or broker down) & paho client restarts)** don't work. Basically I need offline buffered messages to survive client restart and to be sent once client is connected again. I'll try once again to double check it, maybe I missed something.

Comment: Are you setting clean session to true? It probably needs to be false for this to work

Comment: No, clean session is false, of course, but I'll test this tomorrow once again, when I get to work. Will inform you about results. Thanks for your effort so far.

Comment: I haven't managed to make this working. It's highly possible that I am missing some of the mqtt concepts or I am doing something wrong. Steps that I made in order to make this working are:
1) Client connected and successfully published messages every 5 seconds, and they were delevired successfully to the broker
2) Stop broker and wait for 30 seconds or so
4) Shut down application
5) Start broker
6) Start app and client by it, messages are sent, but not ones that were produced while broker was down. (I am setting timestamp for payload.)

Answer (score 0):

setting client id and clean session to false will retain all messages at broker while client is disconnected.

set MaxInflight to queue up messages at client side, while broker is down.